# How to use SYSFUNCT and PUTC or PUTN

Tags: sas

In a macro I have 2 variables, A and B. A is a cycle variable and is an integer from 1 to 12. B needs to be 01 when A is 1, 02 when A is 2, etc, 10 when A is 10, 11 when A is 11 and 12 when A is 12. Basically B needs to be 2 digits, possibly with leading zeros. In a datastep this is easy:

```
B=PUT(A,z2.);
```

But inside a macro this code will not work and SYSFUNC will not work with PUT function. So how can the job be done?

Comment: The answer is in your title.  %sysfunc(putn(&a,z,2));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`putn` works fine.  `putc` is for incoming char arguments ($ formats), `putn` is for incoming numeric arguments like this one.

```
%let a=5;
%let b=%sysfunc(putn(&a,z2.));
%put &=a. &=b.;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. Just out of curiosity, why does it not work within a datastep: data hello; %let a=5; b=%sysfunc(putn(&a,z2.));run; b will be 1 and not 01!

Comment: Because you aren't using quotes. Macro doesn't make a data step variable - it makes text - so that resolves to `b=05;` .

Comment: Why does not put work with  %sysfunction? I had the same problem and had to use putn.

Comment: `put` is a statement and not a function.

Comment: According to this link https://communities.sas.com/t5/General-SAS-Programming/Put-Statement-Put-Function/td-p/183406 it both a statement and a function